# Factors that affect FPS on mobile device in Unity

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am developing a simple player shooting game. It worked fine for me. But when I tried deploying it on the device the FPS reduced to almost 3-4FPS.
Can anyone list out what are the factors that **reduces** the FPS in unity game.

Comment: You do realize there are quite many things in that list? Have you tried profiling?

Answer (score 3):

Minimize the Draw calls, optimize the shaders and Reduce the number of vertices.

[Graphic Optimization](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/OptimizingGraphicsPerformance.html)

[iOS specific Optimiztion](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/iphone-iOS-Optimization.html)

[This article may help](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/AmirFassihi/20130828/199134/0__60_fps_in_14_days_What_we_learned_trying_to_optimize_our_game_using_Unity3D.php)

And try deep profiling of game using Unity Profiler to find the memory overhead.